# How to translate Lao with i18n Ally vscode plugin？

Tags: vue-i18n, i18n-ally

I currently have other languages configured and able to translate, I am not sure if I have found the correct identifier for Lao, I named it la and it seems to show the corresponding flag, but when I use the mechanical translation, it The result of the translation is English not Lao.

Answer (score 0):

Try `lo` instead of `la`. The former should be the correct identifier for Lao.